# Fluent Nhibernate many to many relationship using a surrogate primary key

Tags: nhibernate

I have many to many relationship in my application and I am using fluent nhibernate.

A login can have many roles.  ( A role can also have many logins ).

I have seen many examples of using a composite primary key.

```
        HasManyToMany<Role>(x => x.Roles).Table("Role")
            .ParentKeyColumn("RoleId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("LoginId");
```

Do you know if Fluent/NHibernate supports Many to Many relationships without having the database associative entity (Login_Role) requiring a composite primary key.

I would prefer to have Login_Role use a surrogate primary key.

Cheers,
Andrew

[image]

Comment: You should probably mention WHY you would want this instead of using the natural key?  Is this a "many-to-many-with-payload" scenario?  A company policy?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [idbag](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-idbag):

```
<idbag name="Roles" table="Login_Role">
  <collection-id type="int" column="id">
    <generator class="hilo"/>
  </collection-id>
  <key column="LoginId"/>
  <many-to-many class="Role" column="RoleId"/>
</idbag>
```

I don't think Fluent exposes it yet.